# Java Mail won't work remotely

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've made a Java Mail Servlet to obviously send emails. It works perfectly fine on the production server but when I try and run it on my own home server I get this following error message

javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <*******@googlemail.com>: Relay access denied

```
evo.net.Mail.service(Mail.java:60)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52
```

I changed the hostname variable from localhost to the server's IP in the servlet and it didnt make a difference.

My code:

```
package evo.net;
import java.util.*;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 @WebServlet("/Mail")
 public class Mail extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public Mail() {
    super();
 }

protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)            throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String to = "********";
    String from = "*******@codeprojects.co.uk";
    String host = "codeprojects.co.uk";

    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("root", "*****");
            }
      });

    try {
        Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
        trans.connect("root", "******");

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new             InternetAddress(to));

        message.setSubject("The subject");
        message.setText("Hello World");

        trans.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());;
        out.println("Test");

    } catch(MessagingException mex) {
        throw new ServletException(mex);
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure but i think you need a domain or gmail will reject your request because it might be spam. My guess would be that your production server's hostname is known to google and your homeserver's is not.

Comment: I've just posted my code. The production server belongs to me with my own mail server installed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Google validates the domain you are sending from (or saying you're sending from).

If you're using a development account you will get different behavior than production accounts. It goes this way with every major mail provider out there (including amazon SES)

Your answer lies in [Domain Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys)

Comment: Domain Keys would not help differentiate between emails sent from home vs server IP address.  Also, lack of Domain Keys would tend to have the email end up in Junk, but would not cause relaying to be denied.

Comment: So really theres no solution to this other than using my ISP's smtp server. I could add conditionals in the servlet to decide which server to use.

Comment: That's the whole point of domain keys. Spam is a nasty issue and if you accepted relaying from any-old-place you couldn't even dent spam. Since mass user-authenticated email is a practical impossibility, domain keys does the next best thing which is domain-wide authentication. If you have an authenticated domain, then you're golden. This isn't a java question, it's a net-admin question

Upvotes are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
SMTPAddressFailedException: 554 5.7.1 <*@googlemail.com>: Relay access denied
```

says it all.

For some reason, either your home ISP or Gmail are disallowing your request to relay the email.

Your home ISP might require you to connect to their own SMTP server (this is a common anti-spam consideration).

Gmail might have your home IP on a blacklist (perhaps because your ISP does not carefully prevent spam sending).

**Update**

```
String host = "codeprojects.co.uk";
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
```

indicates you are using an external SMTP server.  Many home ISP's don't allow that, and would give an error like the one you describe.  For running this at home, try changing the SMTP server to that of your ISP.